# Excel - Pulling data from one cell within a list

Tags: excel, powerpoint, spreadsheet

I use PowerPoint as a graphics template to type up football player names and there squad numbers. It can be a long procedure and so far following YouTube tutorials i have managed to create a form in Excel which can update the text boxes in PowerPoint at the click of a button. However you still have to manually input the text first in Excel.

What i want to do is make a tool within Excel where someone can type a football players shirt number into one column, then the column next to it will automatically populate with the corresponding players name.

The full squad of players and there shirt numbers are already in the same spreadsheet. However when a football game takes place only 11 players of the whole squad will play.

What i want to happen is the user be able to type in the number for the each of the chosen 11 players in a column within the spreadsheet and then excel pull the correct players name from this.

I hope this makes sense and is possible.

Thanks in advance to any one who can help.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two columns of the shirt numbers and the corresponding player names then vlookup() will do this, but a warning : are shirt numbers unique i.e. one player one number...
With a list of numbers in D2 to D8 and corresponding names in E2 to E8, then

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D2:E8,2,0)
```

in B2 looks at the number entered in A2 and returns the name. The 0 as last argument makes sure that the nearest name is not returned in a number that is not in the list is entered by mistake.